# Need help on Javascript coding converting to use my html table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table, submit

I have a table which has the number of rows depended on what the number is in the spinner. This does work e.g If I enter 25 in spinner it comes up with 25 rows, if I enter 7 in spinner comes with 7 rows.This is retrieved through the `$spinnerCount`.

The problem is that everytime I submit a question (using a textarea and submit buttom to enter and submit a question) into the table, it creates a new row. So if I had 20 empty rows in the table because I stated in the spinner I wanted 20 questions, then what happens is every time I submit a question, it adds a new row every time, so submitting 20 questions from the textarea would mean the table would contain 20 blank rows and 20 rows with questions. I am guessing it is because of this for example:

```
var enumeratorCell = document.createElement("td");
```

So except creating an element to create a new row, I wanted to retrieve an element so that it submits the question in an existing row (each row contains a text box so question would go into the text box in the row) starting from top row and going down one row every time a question is submitted, rather than creating a new row everytime a question is submitted. The questions would go under the "Questions" column.

Now somebody (user: nnnnn) posted this to me:

Below is an example of a table the user coded himself:

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Below is user's javascript:

```
//If you want to retrieve or change the contents of the existing cells you can do this:

// get reference to the table
var t = document.getElementById("myTable"),
    r,
    c,
    i, j;

// loop through the rows
for (i=0; i<t.rows.length; i++) {
   // get reference to current row
   r = t.rows[i]; //
   // loop through tds of current row
   for (j=0; j<r.cells.length; j++) {
       // get reference to current cell
       c = r.cells[j]; // equivalent to t.rows[i].cells[j]
      // display content of cell
      alert(c.innerHTML);
      // change content of cell
      c.innerHTML = "New value " + i + j;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have tried to manipulate this into my code  but #i could not get it to work. Reason for this is because I don't know to use this javascript for my table. so what I wanted to know is can somebody manipulate this javascript code so that it matches with my table?

Below is code for my table and the textarea where the questions will be entered and submitted:

//My table

```
<table id="qandatbl" align="center">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th><span id="qidhead">Question No</span></th>
    <th><span id="questionhead">Question</span></th>
    <th><span id="optionshead">Option Type</span></th>
    <th><span id="durationhead">Duration</span></th>
    <th><span id="weighthead">Weight(%)</span></th>
    <th><span id="answerhead">Answer</span></th>
    <th><span id="videohead">Video</span></th>
    <th><span id="audiohead">Audio</span></th>
    <th><span id="imagehead">Image</span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $spinnerCount = $_POST['textQuestion'];
if($spinnerCount > 0) {
   for($i = 1; $i <= $spinnerCount; $i++) {?>

    <tr>
    <td class="qid"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td class="question"></td>
    <td class="options"></td>
    <td class="duration"></td>
    <td class="weight"></td>
    <td class="answer"></td>
    <td class="video"></td>
    <td class="audio"></td>
    <td class="image"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php
}
}
?>
</table>
```

//textarea and submit button where questions are typed in and submitted, the textarea and submit button is placed below the table above

```
<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<table id='middleDetails' border='1'>
<tr>
<th class='tblheading' colspan='2'>SESSION DETAILS</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="questionContent">Question:</td> 
<td id="questionTextarea"><textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="questionTxt" name="questionText"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="addQuestionRow" colspan='2'><input id="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" name="addQuestionBtn" onClick="insertQuestion()" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your placeholder rows a "blank" class... remove a blank for each row you add.

Comment: I do  have two columns in table. One column is "Question No"which displays the number of question from the spinner, so all the rows in that column goes 1, 2, 3, 4... to last question number. If I do what you told me to do then for example for my first question, if I remove question No 1, will it add question No 1 again?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your not getting your table element.

Change

```
var t = document.getElementById("myTable"),
```

to

```
var t = document.getElementById("qandatbl"),
```

I think that should do it.

In response to your question in the comments:
move `<?php echo $i; ?>` into the question column `<td class="question"><?php echo $i; ?></td>`

Comment: No, there is much more than just that, if I just do what you told me which I did try before then it would not submit the question from the textarea into the table

Comment: @user1050384 Is there more to the page than what you have posted?

Comment: There are actually more table columns in the table, I editted this in the question, it does work if I leave to just the two columns "Question No" and "Question". But what is happening is that the questions are displayed under the "QuestionNo" and "Question" one by one, how can I just display it under the "Question" column only?